# Return structure with flexible array member

Tags: c, return-value

I need to return a structure with a flexible array member from a C function but can't figure out why it doesn't compile. I know that returning arrays can be achieved by encapsulating them in a struct as follows:

```
struct data_array {
    long length;
    double data[];
};
```

My function looks like this:

```
struct data_array test (int length) {
    struct data_array a;
    double* b = malloc (1000);
    a.length = 1000;
    a.data = b;
    return a;
}
```

However, the compiler returns: "invalid use of flexible array member".

According to the book "21st Century C", the data array in the struct is handled as a pointer (which makes perfectly sense to me). It has not been initialized and therefore there should be no memory been allocated for it to hold its data. (even the compiler doesn't know how much memory is needed for it). So I have to allocate the memory and assign it to my return variable.

So, why does the compiler returns an error? And how can I solve this problem?

Comment: change your double data[] to double *data;

Comment: `the data array in the struct is handled as a pointer` I'm not sure about that...

Comment: You can't return a structure that you create on the stack. Doing so will, for sure, cause stack coruption

Comment: Sure you can - C is pass-by-value (including returned values).

Comment: Also, I noticed you allocate a 1000-*byte* block of memory, but your structure suggests you have a 1000-*element* block. You might want to change that `malloc` parameter to `sizeof(double) * 1000`

Comment: You are using the wrong vocabulary. A variable length array (VLA) is a quite different beast in C, don't mix that up with flexible array member, this would be what you are declaring within your `struct`.

Comment: Not sure why datenhamster received a -1 for this...  +1

Comment: @levengli he's passing the struct by value which contains a pointer to the array. The pointer points to memory allocated on the heap, so its fine.

Comment: You're right @JosephPla, my bad

Answer (score 4):

You may either declare `data` to be an incomplete array (an array without specified dimension) or declare it to be a pointer. (An incomplete array inside a struct must be the last member and is called a flexible array member.)

If you declare it to be an incomplete array, then the structure essentially contains the `length` element and as many array elements as you allocate for it. You must allocate it with the base size of the structure plus space for all the elements, as with:

```
struct data_array *b = malloc(sizeof *b + NumberOfElements * sizeof *b->data);
```

However, you should not return a structure allocated in this way, because there is no way to return the extra elements of the flexible array—the return type of a function would include only the base size of the structure. However, you could return a pointer to the structure. So, you could return `b` but not `*b`.

If you declare `data` to be a pointer, then you create the structure and separately allocate space for `data` to point to, as with:

```
struct data_array b;
b.length = NumberOfElements;
b.data = malloc(NumberOfElements * sizeof *b.data);
```

Here are code samples. First, with a flexible array member:

```
struct data_array
{
    long length;
    double data[];
};

struct data_array *test(size_t NumberOfElements)
{
     struct data_array *b = malloc(sizeof *b + NumberOfElements * sizeof *b->data);
     // Put code here to test the result of malloc.
     b->length = NumberOfElements;
     return b;
}
```

Or with a pointer:

```
struct data_array
{
    long length;
    double *data;
};

struct data_array test(size_t NumberOfElements)
{
     struct data_array b = { NumberOfElements,
         malloc(sizeof *b + NumberOfElements * sizeof *b->data) };
     // Put code here to test the result of malloc.
     return b;
}
```

Comment: Just for the vocabulary, the beast is called flexible array member in the C standards jargon.

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to change base address of the array at line

```
a.data = b;
```

It is not possible to modify the array base address, array base address is a constant pointer.

Answer (score 0):

As to the reason why you cannot convert `double*` to `double[]`, you may refer to [this question that was asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6493185/cannot-convert-from-int-to-int).

As to solve the problem, changing `double data[];` to `double *data;` will work.

**New UPDATE:**

```
double* b = malloc(sizeof(double) * 1000);
```

Comment: @DrewMcGowen Sorry for misleading. But can I ask why I got compiler error in vs2008? the error is `cannot convert from 'void *' to 'double *', Conversion from 'void*' to pointer to non-'void' requires an explicit cast`. Thank you beforehand.

Comment: Are you compiling in C or C++? C++ requires explicit casts.

Comment: By using visual studio, all bets are off (it only supports a subset of c89/c90).

Comment: @DrewMcGowen I don't know about this before. It seems that I always `Compile as C++ Code'. Thank you for your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Structs with flexible array members like yours (where the size of `data` is not given in the struct definition) are to be allocated like that:

```
struct data_array *a;   // pointer!!
a = malloc( sizeof(struct data_array) + 1000 * sizeof(double) );
```

Where `sizeof(struct data_array)` is the constant size of your struct excluding `data` and `1000` is the desired array size.
Of course changing `data` to be a pointer and allocating it seperately will also work, but that is something slightly different.

Comment: That's not a variable length array. `struct`s with flexible array members are to be allocated that way (unless you don't want to use the flexible array member), however.

Comment: @DrewMcGowen But its size is considered 0, it only has (possibly) an influence on padding.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're doing now, my bad.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer of course you're right. I'm ashamed and have edited the first sentence

Answer (score 0):

Few things:

1) change the struct defenation to:

```
 struct data_array {
    long length;
    double* data;
          ^
};
```

2) This is how you should use malloc to allocate memory for your array:

```
a.data =  malloc (length * sizeof(double));
```

**EDIT**

There are too many mistakes, just follow this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct data_array {
    long length;
    double* data;
};
struct data_array* test (int length) {
    struct data_array* a;
    a = malloc (sizeof (data_array));
    a->data = malloc (length*sizeof(double));
    a->length = length;
    return a;
}

int main () {
    data_array* x;
    x = test (5);
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        x->data[i] = i+0.5;
    }
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        printf ("%f\n" , x->data[i]);
    }
}
```

NOTE that you might need to add casting to the types when useing maloc (my visual force me to do so, otherwise it's compile error. But it simply worng).

Comment: The typecasts are only needed in C++ (which is probably why visual studio is complaining)

Comment: @DrewMcGowen I'm aware of that. But visual don't care it is C he generate error anyway.

Comment: I changed the setting as `Compile as C Code`, and there is no complain in vs anymore.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct data_array * test(long length) {
    struct data_array *a = calloc(1,sizeof(struct data_array) + length*sizeof(double));
    a->length = length;
    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use gcc and I think may be this way is ok:

```
struct data_array {
    long length;
    double* data;
};
struct data_array* test (int length) {
    struct data_array* a =(struct data_array *) malloc (sizeof (data_array));
    a->data = malloc (length*sizeof(double));
    a->length = length;
    return a;
}
```